# xml from related tables - when to nest?

Tags: xml

XML data from three related tables, what's the most appropriate, regarding later parsing speed, xslt. Lagre recordssets so memoryreq by parser is an important issue.

```
<rs1-record>
  <related rs2-records>
    <related rs3>
<next rs1..
```

or

```
<all rs1>
<all rs2>
<all rs3>
```

EDIT:
Sorry for being unclear or asking a real dumb question,
I've seen XML-recordsets of both types as above, and if there is any of them prefered, more modern or less memory intense by later parsing I'd be glad to know.

More elaborate example:

```
<order>
  <custid>1234<custid>
  <firstname>Jane</firstname>
  <orderitems>
    <item>Jeans</item>
    <item>Boots</item>
  </orderitems>
</order>
<order>
  <custid>2345...
```

vs.

```
 <orders>
   <order>
     <custid>1234</custid>
     <firstname>jane</firstname>
   </order>
   <order>
     <custid>2345</custid>
     <firstname>...
 </orders>
 <orderrows>
   <orderrow>
     <custid>1234<custid/>
     <item>jeans</item>
   </orderrow>
   <orderrow>
     <custid>1234<custid/>
     <item>boots</item>
```

regards,

/t

Comment: @Marcin is not being [metaphysical](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lomJL.jpg). He's observing that your actual question is *extremely* unclear, if it's there at all. The goal is to get people to understand and therefore answer you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's pretty the same.
But the first is more human friendly. Personally I prefere the first version.

The reader is almost the same but with the second method, it will be more difficult to retrieve items of a specific order.

Comment: agree. I can't find no reason to use the second option, if there is one, please comment.